# How to select specific ID from a csv file?

Tags: csv, filter

I have 2 csv file, one containing all my users with their id, and another with all the trips that users has made. 
I want to select only the user that has made a trip. So I need to extract from the user list, only the one who have the same id on the list of the trip in the column user id.
Have you got an idea to do this ?
Thank you

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can pull both CSVs into Excel and use VLOOKUP to figure that out. Try it out. If you have challenges with that, edit your question and show what you attempted and where the problem was and we can help you further.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve At least tell us what do you want to use - bash/some prog language/some program